# How to turn a video into numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, video

I have a python script in the same folder as a video I want to convert to a numpy array.  My video is called 'test.mp4'.

Within my script, I want to call `someFunction('test.mp4')` and get back a numpy array.  The resulting numpy array should be a numpy array of images, where each image is a 3-d numpy array.

Does that make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read mp4 video to be processed by scikit-image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718238/how-to-read-mp4-video-to-be-processed-by-scikit-image)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The script below does what you want. You may separate part of it into the function.

Code below doesn't check for errors, in particular, production code will check that every `frame*` variable is greater than zero.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
frameCount = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
frameWidth = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frameHeight = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

buf = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint8'))

fc = 0
ret = True

while (fc < frameCount  and ret):
    ret, buf[fc] = cap.read()
    fc += 1

cap.release()

cv2.namedWindow('frame 10')
cv2.imshow('frame 10', buf[9])

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Note you might also consider processing a stream as holding  an entire uncompressed video in memory can run you out of physical memory very quickly.

Comment: what does converting a video to a numpy array get you?

Comment: How long will this code need to execute? Will it take as long as the video is?

Comment: @Hacker The time is determined by decoding speed and is usually much shorter than video duration.

Answer (score 36):

skvideo is a python package can be used to read video and stores into the multi-dimensional array.

```
import skvideo.io  
videodata = skvideo.io.vread("video_file_name")  
print(videodata.shape)
```

For more details:
http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/index.html
and
http://mllearners.blogspot.in/2018/01/scikit-video-skvideo-tutorial-for.html

Comment: How to turn it to numpy array?

Comment: videodata is in numpy format only.

otherwise,
import numpy as np -->
temp = np.array(videodata)

Comment: This is cleaner and simpler than using cv2

Comment: `pip install scikit-video`

Answer (score 2):

Some of the comments here are interested in a speed comparision. OpenCV and skvideo are mentioned by others before me here, so will compare them here.

We will read 1000 frames and compare the speeds.

OpenCV Code

```
def read_video_cv2(n_frames=1000):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rec_q26b_10min.mp4")
    all = []
    i = 0
    while cap.isOpened() and i < n_frames:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        arr = np.array(frame)
        all.append(arr)
        i += 1
    return np.array(all)
```

scikit-video code

```
def read_video_sk(n_frames=1000):
    videodata = skvideo.io.vread("rec_q26b_10min.mp4", num_frames=n_frames)  
    return videodata
```

main function

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(read_video_cv2().shape)
    print(read_video_sk().shape)
```

execution

```
❯ kernprof -l -v test.py
(1000, 480, 1280)
(1000, 480, 1280, 3)
rote profile results to test.py.lprof
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 3.72707 s
File: test.py
Function: read_video_cv2 at line 24

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    24                                           @profile
    25                                           def read_video_cv2(n_frames=100):
    26         1      23785.0  23785.0      0.6      cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rec_q26b_10min.mp4")
    27         1          5.0      5.0      0.0      all = []
    28         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      i = 0
    29      1001       5261.0      5.3      0.1      while cap.isOpened() and i < n_frames:
    30      1000    2366040.0   2366.0     63.5          ret, frame = cap.read()
    31      1000     279732.0    279.7      7.5          arr = np.array(frame)
    32      1000       4769.0      4.8      0.1          all.append(arr)
    33      1000       1984.0      2.0      0.1          i += 1
    34         1    1045494.0 1045494.0     28.1      return np.array(all)

Total time: 3.32195 s
File: test.py
Function: read_video_sk at line 36

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
    36                                           @profile
    37                                           def read_video_sk(n_frames=100):
    38         1    3321951.0 3321951.0    100.0      videodata = skvideo.io.vread("rec_q26b_10min.mp4", num_frames=n_frames)  
    39         1          2.0      2.0      0.0      return videodata
```

We can see that both methods will return numpy arrays of shape `(1000, 480, 1280)` and
`(1000, 480, 1280, 3)` respectively (our video dimensions are 1280x480).

OpenCV with a simple while loop took a total execution time of `3.72s` whereas skvideo took `3.32s`.

So we can see times are very similar and my code is very unefficiently putting a list of arrays into a numpy array. I might suspect we could save some more time here if we pre-allocate the memory for the whole array and write to it efficiently and shave of half sec.

Answer (score 0):

When we look to the video from image processing perspective, we can assume that it is a sequence of images.
From this point, you can loop over the frames of your video and convert them into a `numpy` array.

Here is an example with [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/) libraries, where I'm converting the screenshots from my webcam into `numpy` arrays:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps    


def screenshot():
    global cam
    cv2.imwrite('screenshot.png', cam.read()[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # You can replace it with your video path
    
    while True:
        ret, img = cam.read()

        cv2.imshow('My Camera', img)

        ch = cv2.waitKey(5)
        if ch == 27:
            break

        screenshot()

        data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)

        image = Image.open('screenshot.png')

        size = (224, 224) # Put your suitable size
        image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        image_array = np.asarray(image) # Here, an image -> numpy array
        print(image_array)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```