# How can I get data from 'ravi' file?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video, ravi

**What `ravi` file is:**

> A RAVI file is a video file created by thermal imaging software, such
>   as Micro-Epsilon TIM Connect or Optris PIX Connect. It contains video
>   captured by thermal cameras and is saved in a format similar to the
>   Audio Video Interleave (.AVI) format. RAVI files also store
>   radiometric information, such as temperature and measurement area
>   information collected by the thermal camera.

**My issue:**

I have to work with data from the `ravi` file. I need the temperature value for the pixels (Or the maximum temperature of the frame is enough for me). I would like to check the maximum temperature on a certain frame. The final result would be a report which contains the maximum temperature values on frames (It would be a graph). It is easy to check and process with `Micro-Epsilon TIM Connect` or `Optris PIX Connect` tools but I am not able to use them (I have to write an own one).

**My questions:**

- How can I get the data from `ravi` file (Actually I need only the temperature values)?
- Is there any converter to convert `ravi` file to another (It is not relevant if I can get the data from `ravi` file)?

**Note:**

- The Python language is the preferred but I am open for every idea.
- I have to work with the `ravi` files and I am not able to record new files or modify the 
  recording.
- I have found a site which provides a `SDK` for this type of camera
  but it is not clear for me that get data from `ravi` file is
  possible. Link to `libirimager2` documentation: [libirimager2](http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/index.html)
- If I play the `ravi` file with a media player then it says the used 
  codeck is: `Uncompressed packed YUV 4:2:2` (You can see the getting 
  stream below)

If I parse it with `OpenCV` or play with a media player, I can see something stream. But I am not sure how I can get the temperature...

**CV2 code:**

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("my_test.ravi")

if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Error opening video stream or file")

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Getting stream:**

(I see the same "pink and green" stream in a simple media player as well.)

[image: shown CV2 frame]

**Stream in the official software:**

[image]

**`ravi` file in HexEditor:**

I have found a site about [AVI video format](https://www.file-recovery.com/avi-signature-format.htm). You can see below some lines from begging of my file, perhaps it can help.

```
00000000  52 49 46 46  F8 B1 C6 3F   41 56 49 20  4C 49 53 54     RIFF...?AVI LIST
00000010  CC 7F 00 00  68 64 72 6C   61 76 69 68  38 00 00 00     ....hdrlavih8...
00000020  12 7A 00 00  44 FF DD 00   00 02 00 00  10 08 00 00     .z..D...........
00000030  44 6D 00 00  00 00 00 00   01 00 00 00  08 65 09 00     Dm...........e..
00000040  80 02 00 00  E1 01 00 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00     ................
00000050  00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00   4C 49 53 54  74 7E 00 00     ........LISTt~..
00000060  73 74 72 6C  73 74 72 68   38 00 00 00  76 69 64 73     strlstrh8...vids
00000070  59 55 59 32  00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00     YUY2............
00000080  B4 C4 04 00  80 96 98 00   00 00 00 00  A4 50 00 00     .............P..
00000090  08 65 09 00  00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00     .e..............
000000A0  00 00 00 00  73 74 72 66   28 00 00 00  28 00 00 00     ....strf(...(...
000000B0  80 02 00 00  E1 01 00 00   01 00 10 00  59 55 59 32     ............YUY2
000000C0  00 65 09 00  60 00 00 00   60 00 00 00  00 00 00 00     .e..`...`.......
000000D0  00 00 00 00  69 6E 64 78   F8 7D 00 00  04 00 00 00     ....indx.}......
000000E0  06 00 00 00  30 30 64 62   00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00     ....00db........
```

**Testing materials:**

If you download the `PIX Connect Rel. 3.6.3046.0 Software` from http://infrarougekelvin.com/en/optris-logiciel-eng/ site, you can find several `ravi` files in the "Samples" folder inside zip.

**Additional info from an official documentation:**

[Software for thermoIMAGER TIM Infrared camera documentation](https://www.micro-epsilon.com/download/manuals/man--thermoIMAGER-TIM-Connect--en.pdf)

Video sequences can both be saved as a radiometric file (RAVI) or as a non-radiometric file (AVI). RAVI files
contain all temperature as well as measure area information.

If Radiometric Recording, see Chap. 5.6.2, is not activated the images will be saved as standard AVI file
only containing color information. A later conversion of a RAVI file into an AVI file and vice versa is not
possible

**Update:**

I have tried to use the `PyAV` module to get data. This module is able to handle the `yuyv422` format. I got the same "green-pink" stream and I was not able to get the temperature from it...

**Used code:**

```
# coding=utf-8
import av
import os


ravi_path = "Brake disc.ravi"
container = av.open(ravi_path)
stream = container.streams.video[0]
stream.codec_context.skip_frame = 'NONKEY'
tgt_path = "frames"
if not os.path.isdir(tgt_path):
    os.makedirs(tgt_path)
for frame in container.decode(stream):
    tgt_filename = os.path.join(tgt_path, 'frame-{:09d}.jpg'.format(frame.pts))
    print(frame, tgt_filename)
    frame.to_image().save(tgt_filename, quality=80)
```

**The output of script:**

```
>>> python ravi_test2.py 
(<av.VideoFrame #0, pts=0 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f501bfa8598>, 'frames/frame-000000000.jpg')
(<av.VideoFrame #1, pts=1 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f501bfa8600>, 'frames/frame-000000001.jpg')
(<av.VideoFrame #2, pts=2 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f5018e0fdb8>, 'frames/frame-000000002.jpg')
(<av.VideoFrame #3, pts=3 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f501bfa8598>, 'frames/frame-000000003.jpg')
(<av.VideoFrame #4, pts=4 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f501bfa8600>, 'frames/frame-000000004.jpg')
(<av.VideoFrame #5, pts=5 yuyv422 160x121 at 0x7f5018e0fdb8>, 'frames/frame-000000005.jpg')
```

Comment: have you tried to the read the files as if they were *.avi? You can do this with [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html)

Comment: Sure, I have tried. I have edited my question and added the CV2 details.

Comment: convert your captured video to a numpy array have a look at the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163058/how-to-turn-a-video-into-numpy-array).

Comment: I got error even with "uint64": `buf = np.empty((frameCount, frameHeight, frameWidth, 3), np.dtype('uint64'))
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (20644, 481, 640, 3) and data type uint64`

Comment: Okay, I have managed to solve the above error based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511555/11502612. BUT, I can see the same result if I print the `frame` of `cap.read()`. Eg.: `[[255  68 255]
   [255  69 255]
   [255  72 255]` . It contains only the usual color related info (as I see).

Comment: so what's the issue? Aren't the temperature values embedded in the RGB info? Do you have a calibrated scale?

Comment: Not really. The `ravi` file contains more info. I contains the temperature of pixels and I want to get this info from the file. The temperature is not calculated from the RGB info. Actually, I don't want to see or show the video so I don't care about colors, I want to process the temperature parameter of pixels.

Comment: No need to use uint64, all data is uint8. If you can share a ravie-file, I can take a closer look at your problem!

Comment: First of all, thank for your help. If you download the `PIX Connect Rel. 3.6.3046.0 Software` Software from http://infrarougekelvin.com/en/optris-logiciel-eng/ site, you can find several `ravi` files in the "Samples" folder inside zip.

Comment: I had a brief look. ffmpeg actually supports the format which is indeed in YUY2 format or yuyv422 in ffmpeg-speach. using `ffprobe -hide_banner Brake\ disc.ravi` gives you a ton of metadata that you can have a look at. I also found an R-package that describes everything in great detail. Have a look at https://github.com/gtatters/Thermimage

Comment: You are right, the `ffprobe` command provides the metadata (Probably it will be useful), but if I cannot read the temperature values from the data section then I think I cannot do anything with this metadata.

Comment: According to PyAV document, `to_image` gets an RGB PIL-image, while you need raw bytes. Try with a simple MJPEG-AVI first: you need to be able to read the frame as JPEG-encoded data for which you call `cv::imdecode()` to get the actual content of the frame. Once you check this, you know you are getting raw bytes instead of interpret ones. Default OpenCV written AVI is MJPEG so its simple to generate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know your camera make, but expect the video file to contain raw sensor values as 16-bit unsigned int, which is maybe just named YUV422 in the video header, because they fit the same 16 bits per pixel.

These values you can convert to real valued temperature via a particular non-linear calibration curve. If the RAVI-format is a single file format (as opposed to some legacy IR-cameras with raw-AVI + calibration table) then you should find the location of the few floating point constants and/or table, which make up the equation.

It's possible to reverse engineer the logic, but better ask the correct equation from the manufacturer. For example, what you find on the internet, could be just a legacy version of the calibration curve. Most manufacturers offer calibration libraries together with their devices. Some, out-of-product cycle devices could be a pain to negotiate, but you should get at least a white paper on the topic.

If you use OpenCV, you need to read YUV422-frames raw (16bpp, not 24bpp) and just reinterpret their context as uint16 before applying look up table.

```
// sample C++ code employing private content of OpenCV library
// Particularly container_avi.private.hpp and container_avi.cpp
void mainactual()
{
    cv::AVIReadContainer reader;
    reader.initStream(cv::String("C:/tello/intro2.avi"));
    cv::frame_list frames;
    // initializes the stream
    reader.parseRiff( frames );
    std::cout << "Number of frames: " << frames.size() << std::endl;
    int w=reader.getWidth();
    int h=reader.getHeight();
    std::cout << "size " << cv::Size(w,h) << std::endl;
    // a frame in the middle
    cv::frame_iterator it=frames.begin() + frames.size()/2;

    std::vector< char> data = reader.readFrame( it );
    // In your case, data here is supposed to be 
    // uncompressed YUV422 which is w * h * 2 bytes per frame
    // You might need to modify 
    // bool AVIReadContainer::parseStrl(char stream_id, Codecs codec_)
    // to accept your FCC
    //
    //
    //if ( data.size()!=w*h*2 )
    //{
    //  // error
    //}

    // My video is MJPEG, so I'm confident to just to decode it
    cv::Mat img = cv::imdecode( data, cv::IMREAD_UNCHANGED );
    cv::imshow("image", img ); // looks fine
    cv::waitKey( 0 );
    reader.close();
}
```

EDIT: Tested brake disk.ravi, looks like below. Modified the parser to accept uncompressed YUV2 format and added a hack according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/Aviriff/ns-aviriff-avioldindex

> **dwOffset**
>
> Specifies the location of the data chunk in the file. The value should be specified as an offset, in bytes, from the start of the 'movi' list; however, in some AVI files it is given as an offset from the start of the file.

Not sure what the scrabble is, but looks like a brake disc.
[image]

```
    cv::Mat img;
    if ( data.size()==w*h*2 )
    {
        std::cout << data.size() << " " << w*h*2 << std::endl;
        cv::Mat t( h, w, CV_16UC1, &data[0] );
        // img(y,x) = (float)t(y,x)/10.0 - 100.0
        t.convertTo( img, CV_32F, 0.1, -100.0 );
    }else
        return;
    double mi,ma;
    cv::minMaxLoc( img, &mi, &ma );
    std::cout << "range: [" << mi << ", " << ma << "]" << std::endl;
    cv::Mat gray;
    img.convertTo( gray, CV_8U ); // [0, 255] range saturated
    cv::Mat bigger;
    cv::resize(gray,bigger,cv::Size(4*w,4*h),0,0,cv::INTER_LINEAR );
    cv::Mat jet;
    cv::applyColorMap( bigger, jet, cv::COLORMAP_JET );
    cv::imshow("image", jet ); // looks fine
    cv::waitKey( 0 );
    reader.close();
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your answer! I have already been thinking about the 16-bit thing. But I don't know how I can get the temperature data from it (Based on the documentations the `ravi` file contains the temperature values). I have extracted  the `ravi` file via https://github.com/aurelpjetri/python_avi_parser scripts and I have seen some interesting fields in it. Eg.: MaxTemp, MinTemp etc... But I didn't see the exact temperatures. On the other hand, I really thank your answer, but unfortunately I don't have to explain the `ravi` file or the data storage but also I have to solve it.

Comment: @milanbalazs have you tried: interpret as uint16, then `float t = (float)data[i] / 10.f - 100.f` as found in http://documentation.evocortex.com/libirimager2/html/index.html

Comment: Hmmm.... Probably it can work. But in my understanding I have to parse the `ravi` and interpret only the data chunks as `uint16` and use the `float t = (float)data[i] / 10.f - 100.f` formula to get the temperature. The `AVI` file format contains several other elements based on this site: https://www.file-recovery.com/avi-signature-format.htm. So how can I parse only the data chunks as `uint16`? (Please correct me if I am wrong.)

Comment: @milanbalazs I've seen similar AVI-based IR-formats and as far it's compatible with the frame header struct (e.g. valid FCC's) you can grab frames using a standard reader. I used to be using DirectShow. So no datachunks, but the entire frames. If you use `cv::cvtColor` with COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422 on these frames, you probably see the magenta frame as above

Comment: I sounds good! I will try it afternoon. And okay, let's say I will have a correct `YUV` stream with your solution. And if I use the above formula on the getting frames then I will have the temperature value, am I right?

Comment: @milanbalazs that's my best guess so far. If the temperatures are sound, I suggest you hand pick some pixels from the PI Connect screen, compare and verify the values are correct thru the range.

Comment: I have tried the `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422)` but it didn't really work... I got the following error: `ray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3
`. It means the `cv2.VideoCapture` automatically gets the `uint8` chunks. I am already not totally sure that the `OpenCV` is the best way... Perhaps, It is not possible to get the temperature values from `ravi` file with the `OpenCV`, but I don't know...

Comment: @milanbalazs OpenCV capture is for convinience and it exposes only a subset of underlying library; most users don't need to read compressed formats. Chunks are relatively straightforward to parse with a simple loop https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/avi-riff-file-reference so you see if data is there

Comment: WoW, I have just seen your edited answer. I have to say, it is a really nice job! I will mark your answer as "answer for my question" because it is a really helpful for me (and probably I can start from your code parts).

I have only one more question. Did you try (or manage) to get something temperature data from the frames?

Comment: @milanbalazs the `convertTo` should apply the mentioned simple equation into temperatures. However, the board file in samples folder seems to use different than 0.1 scaling ( 10.0eN anyways) but also a different offset so you really have to compare across a temperature range with the official software to see that equation matches.

Comment: @milanbalazs have you found a python implementation for this? I am a bit stuck on the same problem. Is there a pythonic/python-cv2 way to parse the .ravi files or do I need to use cpp?

Comment: @benschbob91, I have used the `C++` implementation for stream visualization but I parsed the temperature data from the generated `*.dat` file. I have synchronized these two implementation and the tools seems to get the data from the stream (The stream and the "real-time" temperature graph were in sync). You can find how you can export the temperature data to dat/csv file in `Optris PIX` documentation.

Comment: So you have used the C++ implementation to export the .ravi into a readable format (.dat) to compare it to the Pix Connect csv? Correct? However my question is: Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: Not really, I have generated the `dat` file from the `Optris PIX` tools and I have used this `dat` file to visualize the temperature graph with `Python`. BUT, I cannot solve the stream with `Python`. So I have used the above `C++` code (with some modification) to stream the `Ravi` file. If you check the No. frames in `Python` and call the `C++` code from `Python` then you are able to sync the stream and temperature graph.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found out on some footage from a IR-only camera:

- The frames have an extra first line which holds per-frame metadata. It should be discarded for display.
- The image data buffer frames hold 16-bit values (two bytes per pel, low byte first) related to the temperature. I could fit a 4-order polynom with <0.01C residuals, but it's not exactly linear. It is probably logarithmic, not polynomial.
- Note that according to micro-epsilon documentation, there could be up to 3 lines of metadata. The format is  probably camera-dependent, and I was not able to interpret the first-line metadata.

I do not know if all frames from the same .ravi have the same calibration.
Calibration metadata line is very similar from one frame to the next, only three 16-bit values differ slightly (takes two different values), and one increments by one at each frame.

The `float t = (float)data[i] / 10.f - 100.f` formula does not really yield matching temperatures.

Conclusion: only using the provided libirimager can work out the calibration metadata. It could be vendor-depedent too...