# Extracting Temperatures from .ravi file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video, ravi

**My Problem**

Much like the post here: [How can I get data from 'ravi' file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58899981/how-can-i-get-data-from-ravi-file), I have a .ravi file (a radiometric video file, which is rather similar to an .avi) and I am trying to extract the Temperatures in it, to use them together with additional sensor data.

A Sample File can be found in the documentation (http://infrarougekelvin.com/en/optris-logiciel-eng/) when you download the "PIX Connect Software". Unfortunately, according to the documentation, the temperature information is stored in a 16 Bit Format, that Matlab seems to be rather unhappy with.

**How I tried to solve my problem**

I tried to follow the instructions from the before mentioned post, but I somehow struggle to reach results, which are even close to the correct temperatures.[Original Picture with temperatures in the Optris Software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnkIa.png)

I tried to read the video with different methods:
At first I hoped to use the `videorecorder` Feature in Matlab:

```
video   = VideoReader(videoPath);
frame1  = video.read(1);
imagesc(frame1)
```

But it only resulted in this poor picture, which is exactly what I can see, when I try to play the .ravi file in a media player like vlc.

[First try with videorecorder function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbj23.png)

Then I tried to look at the binary representation of my file and noticed, that I could separate the frames at a certain marker  [Beginning of a new frame in binary representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzNAX.png)

So I tried to read the file with the matlab `fread` function:

```
fileID               = fopen(videoPath);    
[headerInfo,~]       = fread(fileID,[1,123392],'uint8');
[imageMatrix,count]  = fread(fileID,[video.width, video.height],'uint16', 'b');
imagesc(imageMatrix')
```

Now the image looks better, and you can at least see the brake disc, but it seems, as if the higher temperatures have some kind of offset, that is stil missing, for the picture to be right.

Also, the values that I read from the file are nowhere near actual temperatures, as the other post and the documentation suggests.

[Getting somewhere!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrF9l.png)

**My Question**

Am I somehow missing something important? Could someone point me in the right direction, where to look or how to get the actual temperatures from my video? As it worked with the cpp code in the other post, I am guessing this might be a matlab problem.

Comment: I can show you how to read the video frames, but I have no idea how to get the temperature, and how to display the frames correctly. Do you want me to post an answer?

Comment: Of course, why not? What method would you use to read the frames? If I can get the original stored values, I might be able to calculate the temperatures,

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you got to calibrate the data? I used the python example given by Rotem but now I am stuck trying to interpolate the data. I have a prn file, but I am quite lost as to what to do next.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by calibrate the data? If you want to use the prn file to extract the original temperatures, the process is very simple: The prn file consists of two columns, that you can see with any text editor. the first column being the sensor value and the second column representing the corresponding temperature. All you have to do is to interpolate this list with your sensor data to get the actual temperature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relatively simple solution for getting the raw frame data is converting the RAVI video file to raw video file format.

You can use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (command line tool) for converting the RAVI to RAW format.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -y -f avi -i "Sequence_LED_Holder.ravi" -vcodec rawvideo "Sequence_LED_Holder.yuv"
```

The YUV (raw binary data) file, can be simply read by MATLAB using `fread` function.
*Note: the `.yuv` is just a convention (used by FFmpeg) for raw video files - the actual pixel format is not YUV, but int16 format.*

You can try parsing the RAVI file manually, but using FFmpeg is much simpler.

The raw file format is composed of raw video frames one after the other with no headers.
I our case, each frame is `width*height*2` bytes.
The pixel type is `int16` (may include negative values).

The IR video frames has no color information.
The colors are just "false colors" created using palette and used for visualization.
The code sample uses a palette from different IR camera manufacture.

Getting the temperature:
I could not find the way to convert the pixel value to the equivalent temperature.
I didn't read the documentation - there is a chance that the conversion is documented somewhere.

---

The MATLAB code sample applies the following stages:

- Convert RAVI file format to RAW video file format using FFmpeg.
- Read video frames as `[cols, rows]` size `int16` matrix.
- Remove the first line that probably contains data (not pixels).
- Use linear contrast stretch - for visualization.
- Apply false colors - for visualization.
- Display the processed video frame.

Here is the code sample:

```
%ravi_file_name = 'Brake disc.ravi';
%ravi_file_name = 'Combustion process.ravi';
%ravi_file_name = 'Electronic board.ravi';
%ravi_file_name = 'Sequence_carwheels.ravi';
%ravi_file_name = 'Sequence_drop.ravi';
ravi_file_name = 'Sequence_LED_Holder.ravi';
%ravi_file_name = 'Steel workpiece with hole.ravi';

yuv_file_name = strrep(ravi_file_name, '.ravi', '.yuv'); % Same file name with .yuv extension.

% Get video resolution.
vidinfo = mmfileinfo(ravi_file_name);
cols = vidinfo.Video.Width;
rows = vidinfo.Video.Height;


% Execute ffmpeg (in the system shell) for converting RAVI to raw data file.
% Remark: download FFmpeg if needed, and make sure ffmpeg executable is in the execution path.
if ~exist(yuv_file_name, 'file')
    % Remark: For some of the video files, cmdout returns a string with lots of meta-data 
    [status, cmdout] = system(sprintf('ffmpeg -y -f avi -i "%s" -vcodec rawvideo "%s"', ravi_file_name, yuv_file_name));
    if (status ~= 0)
        fprintf(cmdout);
        error(['Error: ffmpeg status = ', num2str(status)]);
    end
end

% Get the number of frames according to file size.
filesize = getfield(dir(yuv_file_name), 'bytes');
n_frames = filesize / (cols*rows*2);

f = fopen(yuv_file_name, 'r');

% Iterate the frames (skip the last frame).
for i = 1:n_frames-1
    % Read frame as cols x rows and int16 type.
    % The data is signed (int16) and not uint16.
    I = fread(f, [cols, rows], '*int16')';
  
    % It looks like the first line contains some data (not pixels).
    data_line = I(1, :);
    I = I(2:end, :);
    
    % Apply linear stretch - in order to "see something"...
    J = imadjust(I, stretchlim(I, [0.02, 0.98]));
    
    % Apply false colors - just for visualization.
    K = ColorizeIr(J);

    if (i == 1)
        figure;
        h = imshow(K, []); %h = imshow(J, []);
        impixelinfo
    else
        if ~isvalid(h)
            break;
        end
        h.CData = K; %h.CData = J;
    end
    
    pause(0.05);
end

fclose(f);

imwrite(uint16(J+2^15), 'J.tif'); % Write J as uint16 image.
imwrite(K, 'K.png'); % Write K image (last frame).



% Colorize the IR video frame with "false colors".
function J = ColorizeIr(I)
    % The palette apply different IR manufacture - don't expect the result to resemble OPTRIS output.
    % https://groups.google.com/g/flir-lepton/c/Cm8lGQyspmk
    colormapIronBlack = uint8([...
        255, 255, 255, 253, 253, 253, 251, 251, 251, 249, 249, 249, 247, 247,...
        247, 245, 245, 245, 243, 243, 243, 241, 241, 241, 239, 239, 239, 237,...
        237, 237, 235, 235, 235, 233, 233, 233, 231, 231, 231, 229, 229, 229,...
        227, 227, 227, 225, 225, 225, 223, 223, 223, 221, 221, 221, 219, 219,...
        219, 217, 217, 217, 215, 215, 215, 213, 213, 213, 211, 211, 211, 209,...
        209, 209, 207, 207, 207, 205, 205, 205, 203, 203, 203, 201, 201, 201,...
        199, 199, 199, 197, 197, 197, 195, 195, 195, 193, 193, 193, 191, 191,...
        191, 189, 189, 189, 187, 187, 187, 185, 185, 185, 183, 183, 183, 181,...
        181, 181, 179, 179, 179, 177, 177, 177, 175, 175, 175, 173, 173, 173,...
        171, 171, 171, 169, 169, 169, 167, 167, 167, 165, 165, 165, 163, 163,...
        163, 161, 161, 161, 159, 159, 159, 157, 157, 157, 155, 155, 155, 153,...
        153, 153, 151, 151, 151, 149, 149, 149, 147, 147, 147, 145, 145, 145,...
        143, 143, 143, 141, 141, 141, 139, 139, 139, 137, 137, 137, 135, 135,...
        135, 133, 133, 133, 131, 131, 131, 129, 129, 129, 126, 126, 126, 124,...
        124, 124, 122, 122, 122, 120, 120, 120, 118, 118, 118, 116, 116, 116,...
        114, 114, 114, 112, 112, 112, 110, 110, 110, 108, 108, 108, 106, 106,...
        106, 104, 104, 104, 102, 102, 102, 100, 100, 100, 98, 98, 98, 96, 96,...
        96, 94, 94, 94, 92, 92, 92, 90, 90, 90, 88, 88, 88, 86, 86, 86, 84, 84,...
        84, 82, 82, 82, 80, 80, 80, 78, 78, 78, 76, 76, 76, 74, 74, 74, 72, 72,...
        72, 70, 70, 70, 68, 68, 68, 66, 66, 66, 64, 64, 64, 62, 62, 62, 60, 60,...
        60, 58, 58, 58, 56, 56, 56, 54, 54, 54, 52, 52, 52, 50, 50, 50, 48, 48,...
        48, 46, 46, 46, 44, 44, 44, 42, 42, 42, 40, 40, 40, 38, 38, 38, 36, 36,...
        36, 34, 34, 34, 32, 32, 32, 30, 30, 30, 28, 28, 28, 26, 26, 26, 24, 24,...
        24, 22, 22, 22, 20, 20, 20, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 16, 14, 14, 14, 12, 12,...
        12, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9,...
        2, 0, 16, 4, 0, 24, 6, 0, 31, 8, 0, 38, 10, 0, 45, 12, 0, 53, 14, 0,...
        60, 17, 0, 67, 19, 0, 74, 21, 0, 82, 23, 0, 89, 25, 0, 96, 27, 0, 103,...
        29, 0, 111, 31, 0, 118, 36, 0, 120, 41, 0, 121, 46, 0, 122, 51, 0, 123,...
        56, 0, 124, 61, 0, 125, 66, 0, 126, 71, 0, 127, 76, 1, 128, 81, 1, 129,...
        86, 1, 130, 91, 1, 131, 96, 1, 132, 101, 1, 133, 106, 1, 134, 111, 1,...
        135, 116, 1, 136, 121, 1, 136, 125, 2, 137, 130, 2, 137, 135, 3, 137,...
        139, 3, 138, 144, 3, 138, 149, 4, 138, 153, 4, 139, 158, 5, 139, 163,...
        5, 139, 167, 5, 140, 172, 6, 140, 177, 6, 140, 181, 7, 141, 186, 7,...
        141, 189, 10, 137, 191, 13, 132, 194, 16, 127, 196, 19, 121, 198, 22,...
        116, 200, 25, 111, 203, 28, 106, 205, 31, 101, 207, 34, 95, 209, 37,...
        90, 212, 40, 85, 214, 43, 80, 216, 46, 75, 218, 49, 69, 221, 52, 64,...
        223, 55, 59, 224, 57, 49, 225, 60, 47, 226, 64, 44, 227, 67, 42, 228,...
        71, 39, 229, 74, 37, 230, 78, 34, 231, 81, 32, 231, 85, 29, 232, 88,...
        27, 233, 92, 24, 234, 95, 22, 235, 99, 19, 236, 102, 17, 237, 106, 14,...
        238, 109, 12, 239, 112, 12, 240, 116, 12, 240, 119, 12, 241, 123, 12,...
        241, 127, 12, 242, 130, 12, 242, 134, 12, 243, 138, 12, 243, 141, 13,...
        244, 145, 13, 244, 149, 13, 245, 152, 13, 245, 156, 13, 246, 160, 13,...
        246, 163, 13, 247, 167, 13, 247, 171, 13, 248, 175, 14, 248, 178, 15,...
        249, 182, 16, 249, 185, 18, 250, 189, 19, 250, 192, 20, 251, 196, 21,...
        251, 199, 22, 252, 203, 23, 252, 206, 24, 253, 210, 25, 253, 213, 27,...
        254, 217, 28, 254, 220, 29, 255, 224, 30, 255, 227, 39, 255, 229, 53,...
        255, 231, 67, 255, 233, 81, 255, 234, 95, 255, 236, 109, 255, 238, 123,...
        255, 240, 137, 255, 242, 151, 255, 244, 165, 255, 246, 179, 255, 248,...
        193, 255, 249, 207, 255, 251, 221, 255, 253, 235, 255, 255, 24]);
    
    lutR = colormapIronBlack(1:3:end);
    lutG = colormapIronBlack(2:3:end);
    lutB = colormapIronBlack(3:3:end);
    
    % Convert I to uint8
    I = im2uint8(I);
    R = lutR(I+1);
    G = lutG(I+1);
    B = lutB(I+1);
    
    J = cat(3, R, G, B);
end
```

---

Sample output:
[image]

---

### Update:

**Python code sample using OpenCV (without colorizing):**

Using Python and OpenCV, we may skip the FFmpeg conversion part.
Instead of converting the RAVI file to YUV file, we may fetch undecoded RAW video from the RAVI file.

- Open a video file and set `CAP_PROP_FORMAT` property for fetch undecoded RAW video:

```python
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ravi_file_name)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)  # Format of the Mat objects. Set value -1 to fetch undecoded RAW video streams (as Mat 8UC1).
```

When reading a video frame (using `ret, frame = cap.read()`), the undecoded frame is read as a "long" row vector of `uint8` elements.

- Converting the frame to `int16` type, and reshaping to `cols` x `rows`:
  First, we have to "view" the vector elements as `int16` elements (opposed to `uint8` elements): `frame.view(np.int16)`
  Second, we have to reshape the vector into a matrix.
  Conversion and reshaping code:

```python
    frame = frame.view(np.int16).reshape(rows, cols)
```

---

Complete Python code sample:

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2

ravi_file_name = 'Sequence_LED_Holder.ravi'

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(ravi_file_name)  # Opens a video file for capturing

# Fetch undecoded RAW video streams
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, -1)  # Format of the Mat objects. Set value -1 to fetch undecoded RAW video streams (as Mat 8UC1). [Using cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, 0) is not working]

cols  = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))  # Get video frames width
rows = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))  # Get video frames height

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read next video frame (undecoded frame is read as long row vector).

    if not ret:
        break  # Stop reading frames when ret = False (after the last frame is read).

    # View frame as int16 elements, and reshape to cols x rows (each pixel is signed 16 bits)
    frame = frame.view(np.int16).reshape(rows, cols)

    # It looks like the first line contains some data (not pixels).
    # data_line = frame[0, :]
    frame_roi = frame[1:, :]  # Ignore the first row.

    # Normalizing frame to range [0, 255], and get the result as type uint8 (this part is used just for making the data visible).
    normed = cv2.normalize(frame_roi, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, cv2.CV_8U)

    cv2.imshow('normed', normed)  # Show the normalized video frame
    cv2.waitKey(10)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Sample output:
[image]

Note:

- In case colorization is required, you may use the following example: [Thermal Image Processing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66910372/4926757)

Comment: Its allways stuff like ffmpeg that I dont have in mind, thanks a lot man, that solved my problem! I dont care that much about the pictures/colors itself, I want to look at the raw temperatures, which I can now calculate with the Calibration file. You just saved me a big amount of work! I really appreciate it! Let me know if theres a way to buy you a beer over the internet!

Comment: It's an interesting problem to solve. Don't to buy me beer over the internet :-) I will be glad if you post the method used for calculating the temperatures from the raw data (only if you allowed to post it, and like to share).

Comment: The method is really simple. You get a calibration file with every camera you buy, which includes a calibration curve, that maps the sensor values to a temperature. Then you can simply use interp1, to get the actual temperatures from each frame. I think I am not allowed to share the file itself, but it wont be of great use, as its specifically for the sensor in our camera.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you got to calibrate the data? I used the python example given by @Rotem but now I am stuck trying to interpolate the data. I have a prn file, but I am quite lost as to what to do next.

Comment: @PaulBekaert I don't think Ben noticed your comment. In case you want to contact Ben, add the comment below the question (not the answer), or start the comment with "@BenS".

Answer (score 0):

Each frame holds 16-bit values by pixel  with low byte first and high byte after. To find the temperature you have to apply this formula: `temp = (hi * 256.0 + lo)  / 10.0 - 100.0`.

With low value, you can create a grayscale image. I used this approach with old Pi-160 Optris camera with success. However with new PI-450, it's more difficult since PI Connect does not support binary export now.

I tested the solution with Ffmpeg without success. You get a 16-bit data file, but the offset of real data is incorrect, and thus the temperature is aberrant.

Did you succeed ?

Sample of binary reading:
[image: Binary reading]

Comment: I did succeed using the ffmpeg solution, but only because i had a calbibration curve for my model. I tried your solution as well, but that did not give me the right values at all.

Answer (score 0):

In most of ravi files processed with Ffmpeg, there are non-pixel values on the first line of the raw image.
This first line stores some redondant information such as image width and height.
We have to skip this line which corresponds to the image width. Since data values are 16-bit, we must multiply by 2, to get the exact offset of the binary data. We have also to calculate the exact size  of the image: imageLength = Frame size  - (image width * 2).
In the other case, data are from the start of the file and we can use the frame size (w * h * 2) to copy binary data and update the offset.
To know if it's necessary to calculate the  data offset, we just look at image height. If this value is odd, that means there is a supplementary first line and thus we apply the correction. If the value is even, no correction for the data offset.

This is the same story when parsing the original ravi files. First we have to find the offset of the movi tag in the file. If the movi  tag if followed by the ix00 tag, that means we have just after a series of values that give the offset and the size of each frames from the offset of the movi tag. Real data are elsewere in the file. If ix00 tag is not present, that means that data are just inside the movi chunck, after the 00db flag, and frame by frame. In this last case, we  can also look for the idx1 tag (at the end of the file) which gives access to the exact offset and size of each frame.

Both approaches allow a rather correct image representation in grayscale or in pseudo-color, but the temperature formula provided by the libirimager tool-kit (float t = (float)data[i] / 10.f - 100.f) is incorrect and I do not undestand why, since the formula was correct when I was using raw data produced by the PI-160 camera.

[Fmmpeg test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glr9p.png)

I found an alternative way. In recent ravi Optris file we can get the temperature range in the INFO chunk. Then, it's easy to find the minimal and maximal values in raw data and to interpolate in reference to the temperature scale.
[with correct temperatures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy67A.png)

Comment: Thats because these are not the actual temperature values, but raw sensor values. To get the actual temperature data you have to interpolate them from a calibration curve. I guess, that with your PI-160 they used to store actual temperature values in the movie data, but now they only store the raw sensor data.